# Are there any reliable and supported CSV parsers in C?

Tags: c, parser, csv

I have some algorithms that I need to test on different data sets in CSV format. I was wondering if there is any reliable and supported CSV parser in C that can accept an arbitrary amount of columns and that can maybe parse double quotes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Perl's [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS)  module, notably this file:

https://github.com/Tux/Text-CSV_XS/blob/master/CSV_XS.xs . This is a C file.

XS is Perl's eXension System to call C libraries.

CSV_XS.xs was developed over many years, and the parser is is pretty fast and  robust.